# Bold text with AnchoredText (Python and Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

Is it possible to render the text bold with an AnchoredText?

```
plt.figure() 
ax = plt.subplot(3,1,1) 
anchored_text = AnchoredText("a", loc=2,borderpad=0.,frameon=False)
ax.add_artist(anchored_text)
```

I don't find what parameter I can add to make the text bold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`AnchoredText`](https://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredText) has an argument `prop` which can be used to set the text properties. You may thus use

```
AnchoredText("a", loc=2, prop=dict(fontweight="bold"))
```

to make the text bold.

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText

plt.figure() 
ax = plt.subplot(3,1,1) 
anchored_text = AnchoredText("a", loc=2,borderpad=0.,frameon=False, 
                             prop=dict(fontweight="bold"))
ax.add_artist(anchored_text)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: that's perfect. Thanks.